# Why is the callback called at almost the same time when the readFile is called in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

```js
var fs = require('fs')
function test() {
    for(let i=0; i<10   ; i++) {
        console.time(i)
        fs.readFile(`test2.txt`, function out(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                return console.error(err)
            }
            console.timeEnd(i)
        })
        
    }
}

test()
```

output:

> 6: 114.242ms
>
> 2: 120.270ms
>
> 1: 120.644ms
>
> 4: 120.946ms
>
> 9: 121.326ms
>
> 0: 122.458ms
>
> 7: 121.973ms
>
> 3: 122.365ms
>
> 8: 122.652ms
>
> 5: 123.059ms

When I increase the number of loops, the print time for all callbacks is almost the same.

Comment: try using readFileSync

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your synchronous code takes x ms to run, and your callback takes approximately y ms, all callbacks are queued up after approximately x ms. After approximately y ms all callbacks start to finish.

So f.e. calling `fs.readFile()` 10 times, takes ~5ms, and the callback takes between ~110ms and ~120ms, after ~5ms all the callbacks are running, and after ~115ms they all start finishing.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking javascript to read a file which will intern make a call to the os functionalities to fetch the file, as you are reading the same file everytime it will be in the [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) because it was read recently so it will fetch the file very fast in milliseconds assuming your file size being very small.

Now regarding time being almost the same console.time and console.endTime will give you how much time it has taken to read your file instead of printing the actual time of the system. I think you misunderstood the functionality.

The main reason might be your callback not having any computation try waiting for a certain amount of time randomly